# Postgres 9.1 - Getting the next value

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have some data (sorted by "TimeStamp") that looks like this:

```
      Key     |        TimeStamp        |   Column3   |   ColumnN
--------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------
       1      |   2012-01-01 08:00:23   |     ...     |     ...
       2      |   2012-01-01 08:01:07   |     ...     |     ...
       3      |   2012-01-01 08:02:56   |     ...     |     ...
       6      |   2012-01-01 08:02:56   |     ...     |     ...
       4      |   2012-01-01 08:03:39   |     ...     |     ...
       5      |   2012-01-01 08:04:32   |     ...     |     ...
```

I need to select the next **value** (*not merely the next row*) of "TimeStamp" for each record.

For example, the above data would look like this:

```
      Key     |          Begin          |           End           |   Column3   |   ColumnN
--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------
       1      |   2012-01-01 08:00:23   |   2012-01-01 08:01:07   |     ...     |     ...
       2      |   2012-01-01 08:01:07   |   2012-01-01 08:02:56   |     ...     |     ...
       3      |   2012-01-01 08:02:56   |   2012-01-01 08:03:39   |     ...     |     ...
       6      |   2012-01-01 08:02:56   |   2012-01-01 08:03:39   |     ...     |     ...
       4      |   2012-01-01 08:03:39   |   2012-01-01 08:04:32   |     ...     |     ...
       5      |   2012-01-01 08:04:32   |   NULL                  |     ...     |     ...
```

I have been trying to use a window function for this, but I have not been able to get this result. Any thoughts?

Comment: "*I have been trying to use*" - you should have shown us those attempts.

Answer (score 5):

Even cooler than dense_rank, you can use the [`lead`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html) window function :

```
SELECT Key, ts, lead(ts) OVER(ORDER BY ts ASC)
FROM tbl;
```

Shamelessly stolen [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3ed7a/2/0) link from Erwin's answer.

**Edit**: Hmm, actually it doesn't work *exactly* like you described, since it won't select the next higher value when two values are equal. I won't delete the answer because I think it can be useful in this context, but I'll mark it as community wiki.

Answer (score 4):

This should be *much* faster than correlated subqueries:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS rnk
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT x.key, x.ts AS ts_begin, y.ts As ts_end
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ts, rnk FROM x) y ON y.rnk = (x.rnk + 1)
ORDER  BY x.ts
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3ed7a/1)

- Use the [window function `dense_rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) to get a ranking *without gaps* in a CTE.
- Then `LEFT JOIN` the result to a `DISTINCT` version of itself by an offset of `1` to get the "next" timestamp (and only a single one).
- Alternatively, you could use `GROUP BY 1,2` instead of `DISTINCT` for `y`. I'd expect `DISTINCT` to be faster here, because the sort order agrees with the `ORDER BY` of the window function. But check with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "next" value with subselect like this:

```
SELECT "Key", 
       t1.Timestamp as "Begin", 
       (SELECT min(t2."TimeStamp") 
        FROM the_table t2
        WHERE t2."TimeStamp" > t1."TimeStamp") as "End",
       column3, ...
FROM the_table t1
```

But this query can be slow. If you need it to be fast - just write a simple PL/SQL function.

Comment: This is one of the solutions that I had come up with as well, but (as you pointed out) it is way too slow. What would you recommend to put in the function that would make it run fast? This table has hundreds of millions of records.

Comment: @losthorse Just write a function that iterates throu a simple cursor for `SELECT * FROM the_table ORDER BY time_stamp DESC` (from older to newer). And for every row from cursor `RETURN NEXT` a whole row + `end_timestamp` that you stored in a variable before.